# google apps script to return sheetnames along with isActive and isHidden state, on deploying the web url does not output as expected in doGet function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

- the implement function returns the sheetname, sheet active or not, sheet hidden or not accurately. Function given below -

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var activeSheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();

  var sheetData = sheets.map(function(sheet) {
    return {
      id: sheet.getSheetId(),
      name: sheet.getName(),
      isActive: sheet.getSheetId() === activeSheetId,
      isHidden: sheet.isSheetHidden()
    };
  });

  console.log(sheetData);

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ sheetData: sheetData }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- this outputs accurately what I need, here is shows Sheet136 isActive: true
  [output from doGet function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GJCT.png)

[ { id: 1342625645,
name: 'Sheet135',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 1185282813,
name: 'Sheet136',
isActive: true,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 1301308349,
name: 'Sheet137',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 45843850,
name: 'Sheet139',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false } ]

- But on deploying the web url, the url get request gives the output like this, only on firstsheet isActive: true every time as activeSheet is Sheet136
  [Output from web url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjGGy.png)

[ { id: 1342625645,
name: 'Sheet135',
isActive: true,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 1185282813,
name: 'Sheet136',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 1301308349,
name: 'Sheet137',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false },
{ id: 45843850,
name: 'Sheet139',
isActive: false,
isHidden: false } ]

I'm expecting the output return from doGet function is also same for web url, as I have deployed the web url accurately as if any sheet is Hidden, isHidden: true accurately, error only for active state.

- If first sheet which is hidden the url also gets output like this-
  [ { id: 1342625645,
  name: 'Sheet135',
  isActive: true,
  isHidden: true },
  { id: 1185282813,
  name: 'Sheet136',
  isActive: false,
  isHidden: false },
  { id: 1301308349,
  name: 'Sheet137',
  isActive: false,
  isHidden: false },
  { id: 45843850,
  name: 'Sheet139',
  isActive: false,
  isHidden: false } ]

Comment: The active sheet can be correctly returned when the Spreadsheet is opened by the browser. So, when the Spreadsheet is accessed from Web Apps by the HTTP request, `getActiveSheet()` always returns the 1st sheet. It seems that this is the current specification. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.